# How to pass parameter to custom label mouse double click method

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am new to wpf, is there any way to pass parameter to customer label click method?

Here is the label control in xaml;

```
   <Label Content="tax" MouseDoubleClick="AdjustAmount"></Label>
   <Label Content="due" MouseDoubleClick="AdjustAmount"></Label>
```

Here is code behind method

```
private void AdjustAmount(string amounttype)
{
  switch (amounttype)
{
    case "due":
        {
            break;
        }

    case "balance":
        {
            break;
        }

    case "payment":
        {
            break;
        }
}
}
```

I have tried MouseDoubleClick="AdjustAmount('tax')" but its not working.

Comment: You can use Tag but it would be the same each time. You wouldn't normally click a label anyway. You should use a combobox control with list of items in it, best thing is just create a test project and play around with all the controls

Comment: You can't pass a custom paremeter to the event handler. What are you trying to accomplish here? Maybe you should look into commands.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try:

```
public void AdjustAmount(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  var selectedLotUpdate = (sender as Label).Content;
}
```